# session state timeout vs idle timeout

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-7, web-config

Is the session state timeout setting in the web.config the same as IIS 7 idle timeout setting? If not, which one takes priority? I would like to increase users sessions to a couple of hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Idle timeout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956%28WS.10%29.aspx) is for the application pool as a whole. It kicks in if all the applications linked to the pool have had no activity within the set time.

Session state is per session. This is specifically for a single user session. You can have *many* sessions occurring at any single time.

Comment: @chobo - It is an application pool setting. You can use PowerShell or the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` libraries as well. If you are asking if this can be changed in `web.config`, then I believe the answer is no.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your AppPool's idle timeout is GREATER than your session timeout.

Once your AppPool times out, all session data is lost.

Comment: If that is the case, i,e app idle timeout > session timeout, when your session timeout (assuming that it is cleared straight-away), your app is unable to refer to that session.